# OpenLayers: How to disable the shift key or freehand mode for DrawFeature

Tags: controls, gis, openlayers

I would like to disable the shift key or freehand mode for the DrawFeature Control.
A typical code looks like that:

```
var drawOptions = {handlerOptions: {freehand: true}};
drawFeatureControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(lineLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Path, drawOptions);
map.addControl(drawFeatureControl);
```

There is the option to switch freehand on. But there is nothing to totally deactivate it.
Every time I hit shift the freehand mode is used.

In my use case I would like to use the shift key for another behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Handler/Path-js.html#OpenLayers.Handler.Path.freehandToggle

`drawFeatureControl.handler.freehandToggle = null;` does the trick. Reset it to `'shiftKey'` if you want to re-enable it.

Comment: Perfect! It works. But now the square from the OpenLayers.Control.Navigation() shows up while shift is pressed ;) Do you know the trick for this aswell?

Comment: hum, something like `map.getControlsByClass('OpenLayers.Control.Navigation')[0].zoomBox.deactivate()` ?

Comment: Confirmed, "map.getControlsByClass('OpenLayers.Control.Navigation')[0].zoomBox.deactivate()‌​" disables the "Shift-Zoom-Box-feature" in OpenLayers 2.13.1